# UAC is popping up after each login. How do I discover what's wrong and fix it?

Tags: windows-7, login, uac

I have an almost new PC running Win7 Home Premium. On each successful login I get a UAC popup asking for permission to "modify content on the disk" on behalf of the Windows Control Center. Any clue on how I can diagnose what's the problem and hopefully fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UAC popup comes from the Alienware software that is automatically started to manage the Alienware specific features of the PC. If you update the Alienware software to the most current version the UAC warnings should go away.

To do this, the update check integrated in the Alienware Command Center didn't work for me - it insisted that the software was already at the most current version. I had to download the new version manually from the [Dell support site](http://support.dell.com/). First you have to find your PC model under "Support for home users" -> "Drivers and downloads", then you can download software in the "Application" section. The download is called "Dell-Application" and contains the current version of the Command Center utilities.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the event log for anything from the Windows Control Center, to try to see what it's doing.
2. Download [Autoruns.exe from Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and run it, then clear any checkbox from Windows Control Center. (I'm not sure what that is, by the way. Windows Control Center I mean. That's not good.)

Comment: Maybe I'm begin naive here, but isn't Windows Control Center (or Command Center, can't recall) a piece of windows? The thing that keeps complaining about backups not being scheduled etc. Also, the UAC says it's code signed from Microsoft, so I'm not _that_ worried.

Comment: @agnul I'm always willing to be wrong. :) I'm running Windows. How do I access the Windows Control Center / Command Center?

Comment: Now you're making me nervous :-) I've just checked, it's called "Command Center" and the UAC popup says it has a certificate signed by Microsoft Corporation. It somewhat troubles me that the certificate seems expired in 2011. Some digging in autoruns seems to be in order.

Comment: @agnul Sorry to worry you, I just hadn't heard of it before. A web search shows that it might be someone's product: http://www.bing.com/search?q=%22Windows+Control+Center%22

Comment: Still no idea what it is, but the CLSID in the UAC dialog box seems to be registered to alienware, must be some OEM stuff. (My PC is indeed an alienware one).